# Server disconnected (code: 1006) error while running noVnc

Tags: node.js, websocket, vnc-server, novnc

I have cloned the project https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC on my server(google compute engine). Now according to the readme file, i ran the script

```
bash launch.sh --vnc localhost:5900
```

this returned the

```
Navigate to this URL:
    http://instance_name:6080/vnc.html?host=instance_name&port=6080
```

Now on my local system, I hit the URL

```
server_ip:6080/vnc.html
```

I entered the IP(googled my IP) of another system and port 5900. But it is showing server disconnected(code:1006). I didn't provided any password as I didn't gave any password to vnc server.[image]

In console it is showing error

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.1.236:5900/websockify' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Invalid status line
```

Am I missing something?